# How to extract rasters and points?

Tags: r, extract, raster

I am working on R and creating prediction maps. In my data, I have the location coordinates.

How to extract my rasters and points?

```
library(randomForest)
library(caret)
library(raster)
library(raster)
library(rgdal)

##-----load data 
data <- read.csv("0.10.coordinates.csv",sep=";", header = TRUE)
raster(swi.tif)

rsp.1<-raster("rsp.tif")
twi.1<-raster("twi.tif")
swi.1<-raster("swi.tif")

###load csv of 0-10cm sand,silt and clay %'s and lat/long (x,y) (in E: drive RF folder)
xy<-read.csv("0.10.coordinates.csv")

plot(swi.1)
plot(twi.1)
plot(swi.1)
plot(rsp.1)

stack(swi.1,rsp.1,twi.1,xy)
topo.brick<-brick(rsp.1,swi.1,twi.1,xy)

brick(rsp.1,twi.1,swi.1,data) 
df<-extract(data,rsp.1,twi.1,swi.1)`

Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘extract’ for signature ‘"data.frame", "RasterLayer"’
```

Answer (score 1):

take a look at`?raster::extract` to see what inputs are required and in what order. In any case, you should create a [reproducible example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).
However, here an example with dummy data:

```
library(raster)

# with raster -------------------------------------------------------------
r <- s <- t <- raster()
r[] <- 1:ncell(r)
s[] <- sample(1:10,ncell(s),replace = T)
t[] <- runif(ncell(t))

stacked <- stack(r,s,t)

#points
xy <- cbind(-50, seq(-80, 80, by=20))

#extract
ex <- extract(stacked,xy, df=TRUE)
```

If the extraction takes too long, check out the `terra::extract` or even better a `exactextractr::exact_extract`.

Comment: using `dput` is a terrible approach with these spatial data objects (and it is rather suboptimal in general)

Comment: Sorry, I know it is not a good way for spatial data, but I am used to asking for `dput` data . I edited my answer.

Comment: Even with non-spatial, I think that creating a minimal example is much better, clearer, than using `dput`.

Answer (score 0):

See Elia's example, but from what I gather from your code you should be able to do

```
library(raster)
xy <- read.csv("0.10.coordinates.csv")
s <- stack("rsp.tif", "twi.tif", "swi.tif")
d <- extract(s, xy)`
```